# How can I convert this if, else if statement to switch-statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, refactoring

I'am new to javascript, just gaining the hang of it. This code i wrote for a rock, paper, scissors game works. It changes color of the picked options, for the user and computer and if it's is a draw, changes it to black. Just curious to know if it needs refactoring ? And how to convert it to a switch-statement?

I just cant get the hang of using switch statement with two arguments like this.

```
switch(userChoice, computerChoice){
case userChoice === computerChoice //or 'r' === 'r' :
 //code block
break;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

```
function changeColor (userChoice, computerChoice) {

// If it's a draw, change color to black circle

if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('draw-pick');
    setTimeout( () => {
        document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('draw-pick');
    }, 1000)

// If not a draw, change user pick to green and computer pick to red

} else if (userChoice === 'r' || 's' || 'p' && computerChoice === 'r' || 's' || 'p' ) {
    document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.add('user-pick');
    setTimeout( () => {
        document.getElementById(userChoice).classList.remove('user-pick');
    }, 1000)
    document.getElementById(computerChoice).classList.add('comp-pick');
    setTimeout( () => {
        document.getElementById(computerChoice).classList.remove('comp-pick');
    }, 1000)
}
```

}

Works well, just curious about refactoring and switch-statement.

Comment: [switch - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: So you already know what you want to convert it to but it's up to you to show your efforts in attempting that conversion. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing or refactoring service. The objective here is to help fix your code when it doesn't work as expected or you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should use a switch-case statement for more than 2 cases, but anyway, have a look here:

```js
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = 1

function useSwitch(a,b) {
  switch (a) {
    case b:
      console.log("first case")
      break
    case 1:
    case 5:
      console.log("second / third case")
      break
  }
}

useSwitch(a,b)
useSwitch(a,c)
useSwitch(5,b)
console.log("======")

function useIfElse(a, b) {
  if (a === b) console.log("first case")
  else if (a === 1 || a === 5) console.log("second / first case")
}

useIfElse(a,b)
useIfElse(a,c)
useIfElse(5,b)
```